# VBA (excel) For loop find range not updating inside loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, find

I'm trying to write a macro to cycle through a sheet - find the 'section' header rows, and clear out any values (after the actual heading) and then reapply the formatting.  This is to tidyup after a macro to update the formulas in the sheet.  In the worksheet I have a 'helper column' (sectionHelper) which finds the sections and increments a value (1,2,3,4 etc) - so I just want to find that number, get it's cell address, and then apply the formatting.

The below works for the first instance, but the address doesn't update in subsequent loops. I've checked the values and everything is updating - apart from the 'Foundcell' address, regardless of the fact the What_to_find value is incrementing as expected.

```
Sub Macro3()

' GET NUMBER OF SECTIONS

Dim sectionNum As Integer
    sectionNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("resourceFees").Range("sectionHelper"))

' CYCLE THROUGH SECTIONS AND
' clear formulas from header row

Dim i As Integer
Dim What_to_find As Integer

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

What_to_find = 1

For i = 1 To sectionNum

  Set FoundCell = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=What_to_find)
   
    FoundCell.Select
        Selection.Offset(0, 3).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, _
            Selection.Columns.Count + 13).Clear
        Selection.Offset(0, 3).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, _
             Selection.Columns.Count + 13).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 205, 220)
 
       What_to_find = What_to_find + 1

   Next i
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share the screenshots of your worksheet before (initial) and after (desired) running the code.

Comment: maybe try to have the `findnext` ?

Comment: Everything in the loop works - it's just the Foundcell address that won't update.  I don't know enough about VB to know if that's something to do with it being a range or something else, but I've checked everything else and it's working (including changing the initial search term - which also works)

Comment: Are you sure sectionNum is getting a number higher than 1?

Comment: Yes, if I add: MsgBox ("sectionNum: " & sectionNum & " / i: " & i & " / What to find: " & What_to_find)
I get:
sectionNum: 3 / i: 1 / What to find: 1
sectionNum: 3 / i: 2 / What to find: 2
sectionNum: 3 / i: 3 / What to find: 3